# Bit & Bytes Data Conversion

Tags: unit-of-measure

My query is related mathematical calculations.

Please explain me … how to do any data conversion faster like Gb to MB, Mb to KB, TB to Kb, Kb to TB, …. etc?

Regards
GNS

Answer (score 0):

All those metric prefixes are factors of $1000$ apart, so you just change the exponent on $10$ by $3$.  In computerspeak we often use a ratio of $2^{10}=1024 \approx 1000$ for the prefixes.  It is not very different.

Answer (score 0):

- T =$10^{12}$, G=$10^9$, M=$10^6$, K=$10^3$.
- B=$8$b

So for instance, $x$ Gb to $y$ MB is $x\times10^9$b to $y\times10^6\times8$b.

You can see that $y=\frac{10^3}{8}$. A formula can be derived by this observation...

Comment: if you want to think of a formula, notice that $$y=x\frac{\text{Gb}}{\text{MB}}=x\times\frac{G}{M}\times\frac{b}{B}$$